# Request for the citation feature

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

cstheory.SE and math.SE have a link `cite` in the `link` popin that offers BibTeX and amsrefs for proper citing of questions and answers.

Can we please get that, too?

Comment: I agree. I just got a very good answer: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16801/1342 which I would like to cite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've just turned this on for you folks. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! I may have some feedback on the Bibtex format, later.

Comment: Decided to ask the experts how they would cite SE posts, together with a proposal of my own. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267998/what-should-an-bibtex-entry-for-a-stack-exchange-post-look-like).